# Как через Puppeteer зайти на свой аккаунт Яндекс, который привязан к Google

Tags: cookie, авторизация, puppeteer, веб-скрейпинг

Всем привет. Хочу сделать небольшой скраппер, который бы забирал все мои добавленные в избранное слова в Яндекс-переводчике. Проблема в том, что если я захожу через Puppeteer перенося cookies, то переносится все кроме избранных слов. А если пытаться зайти в аккаунт через Google, то пишет, что браузер не безопасен. Собственно вопрос: как получить доступ к этому списку слов через cookies, local storage или через полноценную авторизацию?

[image: Так это выглядит на моем аккаунте]

[image: А так, когда захожу через Puppeteer]

Вот мой код

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

import cookies from './translate.yandex.by.cookies.json' assert {type: 'json'}


const getTranslates = async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.setCookie(...cookies)
  await page.goto('https://translate.yandex.by')

  // await browser.close()
}

getTranslates();
```